# Error reading information from a JTable empty string error

Tags: java, string, jtable

Does the following code make sense?  I'm basically trying to read in values from a JTable and cast them to double.  But I'm getting the following errors.  Specifically the error in the line 1567 that reads `percentageValueDouble=Double.parseDouble(percentageValueString);`
But I don't understand what the errors mean or how to fix them.

This is the source code:

```
if((gradesTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, j)!=null)&&(gradesTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, j)!="")){
    percentageValueObject=gradesTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, j);
    percentageValueString=percentageValueObject.toString();
    percentageValueDouble=Double.parseDouble(percentageValueString);
    }
    else
        percentageValueDouble=(Double) null;
```

And this is the error given:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at Gradebook$13.mousePressed(Gradebook.java:1567)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the value got is not Double for sure.

**Reason**

You definitely don't have a double in the cell.

You may have something like 50%, 10.5% or something similar.

What you need is 50 , 10.5. Just exclude '%'.

**P.S.** And certainly the reason is

You should use **equals()** method to check for empty string.

```
!gradesTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, j).equals("")
```

Or alternatively you can check for length as follow:

```
gradesTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, j).length()>0
```

**Edit:**

You are checking for empty string using **==** so the **if** block is running even if the string is empty. So the problem will be solved using **equals()** method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the .equals() method!  The strange thing is that the values being read in to the JTable in fact are 50 and 100 without any other characters attached.   Ultimately, I changed the == to .equals() and even though that fixed one error the same "empty string" error reads on the IDE.

Comment: can you clean the project and post new stacktrace

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response.  I did end up getting it fixed using your advice.  Thank you very much for your help.